deploying ruby and rails project to Heroku
heroku logs --tail
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208692+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208692+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208693+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208698+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208699+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208700+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208700+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208700+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.208707+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:42.284492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-04-17T04:11:42.306506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-04-17T04:11:42.309823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-04-17T04:11:49.544411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`
2024-04-17T04:11:52.065007+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2024-04-17T04:11:52.065052+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.8 application starting in production
2024-04-17T04:11:52.065053+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
2024-04-17T04:11:52.953545+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954510+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:33:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /app/app/controllers/semesters/repositories_controller.rb to define constant Semesters::RepositoriesController, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954512+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954513+00:00 app[web.1]: raise Zeitwerk::NameError.new(msg, cref.last)
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954513+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954515+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:31:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954516+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `const_get'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954516+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:135:in `cget'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:175:in `block in actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:40:in `block in ls'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954519+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954519+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:25:in `ls'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954524+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:170:in `actual_eager_load_dir'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954524+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954524+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:16:in `block in eager_load'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `synchronize'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader/eager_load.rb:10:in `eager_load'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954526+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:379:in `block in eager_load_all'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954526+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954526+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.12/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:377:in `eager_load_all'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954526+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:74:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954527+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954528+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954528+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954528+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954530+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954530+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954530+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:372:in `initialize!'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954532+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954532+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954532+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954536+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954537+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954537+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:312:in `block in start'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:379:in `handle_profiling'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/server.rb:311:in `start'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:38:in `start'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:143:in `block in perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954539+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954539+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954540+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954540+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954540+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954540+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954541+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954541+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954542+00:00 app[web.1]: from <internal:/app/vendor/ruby-3.2.1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2024-04-17T04:11:52.954543+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2024-04-17T04:11:53.044985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-04-17T04:11:53.080689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-04-17T04:11:54.240320+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tag-team-20617dde09ea.herokuapp.com request_id=b29929d9-6f95-4d7a-93f8-9c4e715e1470 fwd="73.5.84.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-04-17T04:11:54.361786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tag-team-20617dde09ea.herokuapp.com request_id=77c2cbaa-f765-4ce6-be91-e55226df0501 fwd="73.5.84.100" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-04-17T04:11:30.368142+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 8ceb9ef8 by user hrizeq@memphis.edu
2024-04-17T04:11:30.368142+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user mail.com
2024-04-17T04:11:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

i am trying to deploy my project to Heroku and actually it deployed but whenever i try to run the domain, i keep getting this error, i have tried everything i am not sure what is going on

There is this error expected file /app/controllers/semesters/repositories_controller.rb to define constant Semesters::RepositoriesController, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError). What does that file look like? It might be that there is a typo in the file or your application is not following naming conventions.

Why have you tagged this with Java and JSON? It doesn't look like either of those are relevant.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your controllers seem to be namespaced under semesters folder. But you probably still name your controller RepositoriesController instead of Semesters::RepositoriesController

Please show us the repositories_controller.rb file.
